# Custom JavaScript scrolling on iOS 8 - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

Am building a page for iOS 8 where I need to completely block built-in scrolling and scroll the page through javascript alone (Eg. using scrollTo() method).

I don't want to hide the scrollbars, just to block the scrolling action (seems like it's done through event.preventDefault() ) and implement scrolling in JavaScript.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has a [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll), unfortunately it is not cancelable (i.e. `event.preventDefault()` does not work).

If however you're only using touch enabled devices and scrolling is done through touch the [touchmove event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove) will be fired upon scrolling, which is cancelable, using `event.preventDefault()`, and will prevent scrolling. Note that this also prevents other actions requiring touchmove such as zooming.

Another solution, which might look a bit glitchy on some devices, is to store the scroll position of the document at the place you want to lock it and go to those coordinates whenever a user is scrolling. Something like the following:

```
var locked = false,
    posX = 0,
    posY = 0;

var lock = function(){
    //assign the current coordinates to the position variables
    var doc = document.documentElement;
    posX = (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0);
    posY = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);

    locked = true;
};
var unlock = function(){
    locked = false;
};

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    if(locked)
        scrollTo(posX, posY);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Kiren could you elaborate a bit on your last solution (did not completely understood it); when exactly would I store the scroll position of the document? Thanks for the reply, by the way.

Comment: The scroll position is the position where you want the document to be locked at. Here's an [example](http://jsbin.com/qenowo/edit?js,output)

Comment: That's really good but I need to be able to implement scrolling through JS once it is locked (scrolling will always be locked). So like you initially mentioned touchmove event allows event.preventDefault(); I think that may be my only door-way. Thanks anyways!

Comment: As long as you change `posX` and `posY` before you scroll through JS it should be working fine. But I think that using the `touchmove` event is a safer bet as I've experienced stuttering on mobile devices with the other solution.

Comment: Well, I did find I can implement custom movement of scroll position after preventing touchmove event so I'll be focusing on a solution in that direction. I'll mark this as the right answer, thanks @Kiren!

Answer (score 0):

A couple years ago I made a cordova/phonegap app using [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5). At the time it helped me through some seriously bad scroll view issues.

You can disable scroll, force move to etc

Perhaps it could work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Using iScroll is not an option, sadly. I just need it to work on iOS 8. Particularly to get around the gap/lag between device re-paint and javascript execution during scrolling/swiping. Even with iOS 8, javascript execution during scrolling is not 100% seamless; in other words, if I move something on the screen while I scroll, it will always be with a slight delay. I have a working example with a clip rectangle that I am moving around in an onscroll handler; that would be the perfect example to show.

Comment: Yeah that would be great let me know when you've finished your example so I can help you further!

Comment: It's been done for a long time, lotsa headaches :) [link](http://foretellings.com/dev/index.html)

Comment: In there I am trying to re-position a clip: rect() area on a position: fixed div with an image background. Repositioning is done in a onscroll event handler (I tried setIntervals, touchmove event, same result). Animation is seamless/smooth on desktop but with delays on iOS

Comment: @Sonofkyuss Just wondering based on your example, why aren't you using CSS for this? This would solve the problem of late re-painting. I simply added background-color to the text and got the same result without any javascript, [here](http://jsbin.com/kufigo/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @Kiren Oh, yes that would have been the perfect solution, I know; sadly I'm not allowed to tamper with the background of the content in the page (what's above and below the reveal area). Created a [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641623/figure-out-seamless-scrolling-w-position-fixed-element-on-ios-8), if you're interested to take a look. That's basically why I posted this question: to find a workaround to achieve that effect seen in the example.