# Figure out seamless scrolling w/ position: fixed element on iOS 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

What I need to achieve can be seen on [this demo](http://break-even.celtra.com/preview/2624e0c2).

Basically a page with a rectangle area that you reach by scrolling down, where there's content that appears as if it were a position: fixed element. In the demo above, the revealed content is a page displayed through an iframe - I'm happy with just an image.

I only need this to work on iOS 8. From what I can see, the demo does it through some custom scrolling mechanism. I suspect they have somehow overwritten scrolling altogether - although I can't confirm it's a custom scrolling framework like iScroll.

My own approach was to re-position a clip: rect area on a position: fixed background image, through a onscroll handler. Sort of like moving a mask around, on an image. [Example here](http://foretellings.com/dev/index.html)

The code I use in my JS onscroll handler to re-position the clipping rectangle:

```
topY = adDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset - adDiv.ownerDocument.documentElement.clientTop;
scrollT = (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || document.body.scrollTop;
newY = topY - scrollT;
newHeight = rectHeight + newY;
document.getElementById("bgImg").style.clip = "rect("+newY+"px,1900px,"+newHeight+"px,0px)";
```

I'd be happy with this if there weren't for a delay while re-positioning the clip: rect area; you can see it if you test on anything iOS 8 (there is a slight delay when you scroll/swipe up and down around the area that reveals the image). Wasn't able to overcome this and fear it's by-design.

**EDIT: please note I need to have the content that is above and below the reveal area, see-through; so with a transparent background that would allow you to see the page's background; can't mess with anything above and below.**

Comment: A snapshot w/ description of the delay bug in question: [link](http://imgur.com/17OD7Vf)

Answer (score 1):

I've stripped the demo you linked down to the essentials, in which there seems to be three elements of importance, one container, one which is used for the clipping, and the third for the content.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="clip-box">
      <div class="content">
          ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The "container" defines the area you want to use in line with the text;

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
}
```

The clip-element is where the interesting happens. It's made to fill the parent, which makes the `clip: rect(auto ... auto)` clip the element (and therefore also it's children) at its edges. It's important that this element is set `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`, as clipping only applies to absolutely positioned elements.

```
.clip-box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    clip: rect(auto auto auto auto);
}
```

Lastly we have the content as a child of the clip-element. It is set to a fixed position but will only render in the clip-rect area defined by the parents’ bounding-box.

```
.content {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

Here's a snippet of the above which uses only css.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/500/");
  background-size: cover;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.content p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.window {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
}
.clip-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  clip: rect(auto auto auto auto);
}
.content {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum
  <br>dolor sit amet,
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <br>Morbi convallis
  <br>accumsan neque,
  <br>eu accumsan magna
  <br>laoreet cursus.
  <br>Etiam feugiat mattis
  <br>nunc eget luctus.
  <br>Proin vel dictum est.
  <br>Nullam suscipit quam
  <br>at ullamcorper vestibulum.
  <br>Lorem ipsum
  <br>dolor sit amet,
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <br>Curabitur rutrum
  <br>elementum ligula,
  <br>suscipit sodales
  <br>nisl convallis a.
</p>
<div class="window">
  <div class="clip-box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/400/">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum
        <br>dolor sit amet,
        <br>consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <br>Morbi convallis
        <br>accumsan neque,
        <br>eu accumsan magna
        <br>laoreet cursus.
        <br>Etiam feugiat mattis
        <br>nunc eget luctus.
        <br>Proin vel dictum est.
        <br>Nullam suscipit quam
        <br>at ullamcorper vestibulum.
        <br>Lorem ipsum
        <br>dolor sit amet,
        <br>consectetur adipiscing elit.
        <br>Curabitur rutrum
        <br>elementum ligula,
        <br>suscipit sodales
        <br>nisl convallis a.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum
  <br>dolor sit amet,
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <br>Morbi convallis
  <br>accumsan neque,
  <br>eu accumsan magna
  <br>laoreet cursus.
  <br>Etiam feugiat mattis
  <br>nunc eget luctus.
  <br>Proin vel dictum est.
  <br>Nullam suscipit quam
  <br>at ullamcorper vestibulum.
  <br>Lorem ipsum
  <br>dolor sit amet,
  <br>consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <br>Curabitur rutrum
  <br>elementum ligula,
  <br>suscipit sodales
  <br>nisl convallis a.
</p>
```

---

You should however note that the `clip` property is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) and developers are advised to use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) instead. This is an experimental technology though and if you're only wanting to use images anyway I'd recommend using [`background-attachment: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) which will give you the same result as the code above.

Comment: Hey @Kiren, sorry for the delay in responding. Thanks for the example above. I did try it on an iPad w/ iOS 8.1 but I am still getting that delay in re-painting the clip: rect(auto auto auto auto). So what I did myself initially was the exact same thing: I stripped the demo to it's basics (html/css) and hoped it would work; it did on desktop but did not work on actual iOS devices; then I took a closer look at it and I am 99% it uses some obfuscated JavaScript for the scrolling of the page.